# determine duration of certain state of a device in table with multiple devices

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

I have a table which holds the deviceId, the state of a device (Bypassed) and a timestamp (Regtime)

```
+----------+--------+-----------------+
| DeviceId | Bypass |     RegTime     |
+----------+--------+-----------------+
|       14 |      0 | 30-5-2018 02:14 |
|       12 |      0 | 30-5-2018 02:14 |
|       14 |      0 | 30-5-2018 02:15 |
|       14 |      0 | 30-5-2018 02:15 |
|       12 |      0 | 30-5-2018 02:15 |
|       12 |      0 | 30-5-2018 02:15 |
|       14 |      0 | 30-5-2018 02:16 |
|       12 |      0 | 30-5-2018 02:16 |
|       14 |      1 | 30-5-2018 02:17 |
|       12 |      0 | 30-5-2018 02:17 |
|       14 |      1 | 30-5-2018 02:18 |
|       12 |      0 | 30-5-2018 02:18 |
|       14 |      1 | 30-5-2018 02:19 |
|       12 |      0 | 30-5-2018 02:19 |
|       14 |      0 | 30-5-2018 02:20 |
|       12 |      0 | 30-5-2018 02:20 |
|       14 |      0 | 30-5-2018 02:21 |
|       12 |      0 | 30-5-2018 02:21 |
|       14 |      0 | 30-5-2018 02:22 |
|       12 |      1 | 30-5-2018 02:22 |
|       14 |      0 | 30-5-2018 02:23 |
|       12 |      1 | 30-5-2018 02:23 |
|       14 |      0 | 30-5-2018 02:24 |
|       12 |      0 | 30-5-2018 02:24 |
+----------+--------+-----------------+
```

Now I need to determine the time that a device is in Bypass state (Bypass = 0).

I have tried several things with windowing and `First_Value` and `Last_Value`, but the problem here seems to be that I can only partition by DeviceId.

So when a device was in Bypass and then came out of it, the `first_value` is still the `first_value` of all the devices

Comment: So what do you want for output? Do you want the first value when the deviceid is in state 1 ? Can you make a sample of what you want as output?

Comment: I now see that my example is not very good. I changed the question a bit (Bypass=0)
What I need is the duration of the consqutive bypass values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands type of problems with state for which device is in state 1 is the island.

<kbd>**[See updated live demo](http://rextester.com/KKAVR44355)**</kbd>
You can use a query like below to get your data

```
;with numberedT as 
(
    select *, 
    rn =ROW_NUMBER() over(Partition by deviceId order by RegTime), 
    rn2=ROW_NUMBER() over(Partition by deviceId,Bypass order by RegTime)
    from t 
)

select 
    deviceid,
    BypassStart=min(Regtime),
    BypassEnd = max(Regtime),
    TimeInBypassState=datediff(mi,min(Regtime),max(Regtime))
from numberedT
group by deviceid,rn2-rn, Bypass
Having Bypass=1
order by deviceid
```

Comment: Now I have the total time the dvice was in bypass. The problem is that I want to know the duration of the bypass-time from consequtive measurements. I allready noticed the example wasn't the best. So let's presume I want to know how long the device is not in Bypass (bypass=0) until it gets in bypass again. So when you look in the example, I need to know the total time that Bypass = 0 before it switches to 1 again. When Bypass switches to 0 again we need to know the time until it switches to 1 again

Comment: based on your answer and comment I've updated my answer. please check and let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: The final Select can be simplified to `select ...
where Bypass=1
group by deviceid,rn2-rn` as you don't care about Bypass=0 rows. And, of course, the LAG is not used...

Answer (score 0):

I *assume* you mean something like this. If not, then provide expected results like plaidDK asked for:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE Device (DeviceID int,
                     Bypass bit,
                     RegTime datetime2(0));
GO
INSERT INTO Device
VALUES
(14,0,'2018-05-30T02:14:00.000'),
(12,0,'2018-05-30T02:14:00.000'),
(14,0,'2018-05-30T02:15:00.000'),
(14,0,'2018-05-30T02:15:00.000'),
(12,0,'2018-05-30T02:15:00.000'),
(12,0,'2018-05-30T02:15:00.000'),
(14,0,'2018-05-30T02:16:00.000'),
(12,0,'2018-05-30T02:16:00.000'),
(14,1,'2018-05-30T02:17:00.000'),
(12,0,'2018-05-30T02:17:00.000'),
(14,1,'2018-05-30T02:18:00.000'),
(12,0,'2018-05-30T02:18:00.000'),
(14,1,'2018-05-30T02:19:00.000'),
(12,0,'2018-05-30T02:19:00.000'),
(14,0,'2018-05-30T02:20:00.000'),
(12,0,'2018-05-30T02:20:00.000'),
(14,0,'2018-05-30T02:21:00.000'),
(12,0,'2018-05-30T02:21:00.000'),
(14,0,'2018-05-30T02:22:00.000'),
(12,1,'2018-05-30T02:22:00.000'),
(14,0,'2018-05-30T02:23:00.000'),
(12,1,'2018-05-30T02:23:00.000'),
(14,0,'2018-05-30T02:24:00.000'),
(12,0,'2018-05-30T02:24:00.000');
GO
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DeviceID ORDER BY RegTime ASC) AS RN
    FROM Device
    WHERE Bypass = 1)
SELECT DeviceID,
       Bypass,
       RegTime
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1 ;

GO
DROP TABLE Device;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to determine the duration from bypass 1 within a device you can do it like this:

**Sample Data**

```
create table #temp
(deviceid int,bypass int, regtime datetime)

insert into #temp 
values
(14 , 0 ,'2018-05-30 02:14'),
(12 , 0 ,'2018-05-30 02:14'),
(14 , 0 ,'2018-05-30 02:15'),
(14 , 0 ,'2018-05-30 02:15'),
(12 , 0 ,'2018-05-30 02:15'),
(12 , 0 ,'2018-05-30 02:15'),
(14 , 0 ,'2018-05-30 02:16'),
(12 , 0 ,'2018-05-30 02:16'),
(14 , 1 ,'2018-05-30 02:17'),
(12 , 0 ,'2018-05-30 02:17'),
(14 , 1 ,'2018-05-30 02:18'),
(12 , 0 ,'2018-05-30 02:18'),
(14 , 1 ,'2018-05-30 02:19'),
(12 , 0 ,'2018-05-30 02:19'),
(14 , 0 ,'2018-05-30 02:20'),
(12 , 0 ,'2018-05-30 02:20'),
(14 , 0 ,'2018-05-30 02:21'),
(12 , 0 ,'2018-05-30 02:21'),
(14 , 0 ,'2018-05-30 02:22'),
(12 , 1 ,'2018-05-30 02:22'),
(14 , 0 ,'2018-05-30 02:23'),
(12 , 1 ,'2018-05-30 02:23'),
(14 , 0 ,'2018-05-30 02:24'),
(12 , 0 ,'2018-05-30 02:24')
```

**SQL Script**

```
select x.deviceid,x.bypass,regtime,case when x.bypass = rn then DATEDIFF(SS,regtime,maxtime) else 0 end as DurationInSeconds from (
select *,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by a.deviceid,a.bypass order by regtime) as rn
from #temp a
) x

cross apply (select MAX(regtime) as maxtime,deviceid,bypass from #temp b where  B.bypass = 1 and x.deviceid = B.deviceid   group by deviceid,bypass ) c
```

And if you only want the information on device info:

**SQL2**

```
select x.deviceid,x.bypass,case when x.bypass = rn then DATEDIFF(SS,regtime,maxtime) else 0 end as DurationInSeconds from (
select *,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by a.deviceid,a.bypass order by regtime) as rn
from #temp a
) x

cross apply (select MAX(regtime) as maxtime,deviceid,bypass from #temp b where  B.bypass = 1 and x.deviceid = B.deviceid and rn= 1 and x.bypass = 1   group by deviceid,bypass ) c
```

Answer (score 0):

Output should be like:

| DeviceId |   BypassStart   |    BypassEnd    | BypassDuration |

|----------|-----------------|-----------------|----------------|

| 12 | 30-5-2018 02:22 | 30-5-2018 02:23 |              1 |

|       14 | 30-5-2018 02:17 | 30-5-2018 02:19 |              2 |

But when another occurence of Bypass = 1 and DeviceId = 14 shows up for a number of consquetive records, and in between Bypass=1 occured, I should get an extra row for that Decvice, with the total time of the these rows